# How can I Monitor an Oracle Database installed in a GCE instance in Stackdriver?

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I have an Oracle database installed in a Google Cloud Platform instance, is there any plugin for monitoring it?
What options do I have?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out anything in the end? I also saw that there isn't any support for monitoring Oracle DB in Stackdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Oracle version that you are using, you could download [Oracle Enterprise Manager](https://www.oracle.com/enterprise-manager/index.html).

Also note that Google does not guarantee any setup related to third party sw/db (including Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver for Oracle Database support is now available via the Google Stackdriver integration with BindPlane which provides metric and log monitoring for non-GCP data sources for Stackdriver.

It is fully supported by Google and is free (other than typical Stackdriver consumption fees).

More info can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/monitoring-on-premises-resources-with-stackdriver-and-blue-medora

Info specifically around Bindplane for Oracle Database here:

https://docs.bindplane.bluemedora.com/docs/oracle-database